# You must provide a screenshot for 5.5-inch Retina display (for 4.7 inch)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

When I press **Submit For Review** button in **iTunes Connect**, I get errors

*You must provide a screenshot for 5.5-inch Retina display, because your app **binary supports 5.5-inch Retina displays.***

*You must provide a screenshot for 4.7-inch Retina display, because your app **binary supports 4.7-inch Retina displays.***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was because I added **launching images** for 5.5 and 4.7 displays. App should has nothing for them. So I remove this images and *iTunes Connect* eat it normally :)

[image: Clear]

Comment: agree, but Skitch is my favourite tool. Use it everywhere :)

Comment: Its not possible to draw freehand circles in Skitch? Foo.

Comment: oh, i figured out how to do it. Is it "sexy" now? :)

Comment: aaaaaaahh. beatiful. However I can't give you another +1, so don't worry.

Comment: I can't seen Retina HD 5.5 and Retina HD 4.7. I'm using XCode 5.1.1 and XCode 6.

Comment: @AntonGaenko are u there?

Comment: i just not getting such message Retina 5.5 inch and Retina 4.5 inch . how can i do this ? my app is not targeting any such devices .. i am getting this problem from last one week. please help

Comment: @SBM To see that launch images in XCode 6 you can go to Utilities right tab/Attributes inspector. Just select iOS 8 and Later and you will see this fields.

Comment: i think that you all have another issue with that

Comment: It appears that iTunes Connect has changed its requirements in the last few days.  See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088961/you-must-provide-a-screenshot-for-5-5-inch-retina-display-because-your-app-bin

Answer (score 0):

In addition, make sure that you don't have a LaunchImage.xib active in the project. I had this same problem, which persisted even though I removed my 4.7/5.5" images.

I found that iTunes Connect accepted my build when I removed the LaunchImage.xib and cleared that out of the "Launch Screen File" field on the target's General panel in Xcode.

In my case it was because I started with an iOS8 based project, and then manually converted it to an iOS7.1+ compatible project.

Finally, I don't know if it's required, but it may also be necessary to uncheck the "iOS 8 and Later" options for any images you have as well. These can be found on the properties panel for each image within your "Images.xcassets".

Answer (score 0):

This was a **validation error** by iTunesConnect. I put in a bug report on Thursday Dec 4th, 2014 and as of Friday around 3:00pm PDT on December 5th, 2014 **it was fixed**. Thanks to the Apple Developer Technical Support for interfacing with iTunesConnect and showing them that their "validation routines" needed to be addressed to alleviate this issue.

Again, if you put your app up previously and added 4.7" and 5.5" screenshots simply to get past this bug then you have also inadvertently caused the App Store to list your app as "optimized for iPhone 6/iPhone 6 Plus" in the App Store.  You should probably do another release and remove those screenshots (the only way to add/remove screenshots is another version release) ... because it is not valid to have them there if your App is truly not optimized for those screens. You **will** get complaints by customers... that your app is showing as "optimized" ... when really it is "zoomed".

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you check that all languages have screenshots for the missing sizes. Each language needs screenshots uploaded, even if they are the same.